# Maintain adb port forwarding after reconnect

Tags: adb

I've noticed that, when I do

```
adb reverse tcp:12345 tcp:12345
```

and then later disconnect/reconnect the phone, `adb reverse --list` will come up empty.

Is there a way to persist this port forwarding?  That is, I'd like it so that, whenever I connect to a device (either through USB or OpenSTF), the port forwarding is automatically established.

Comment: Write yourself a batch file that connects and establishes the port forwarding.

Comment: How do I make that script run whenever I plug the phone into the USB port?

Comment: ADB has no such feature. You can only use such a functionality if it is provided by your OS.